# Undefined Method 'underscore'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, single-table-inheritance

I'm trying my hand at STI using Thibault's tutorial: https://samurails.com/tutorial/single-table-inheritance-with-rails-4-part-3

It's been working fine up till the dynamic paths part where I get 'undefined method `underscore' for nil:NilClass' for this snippet

```
def format_sti(action, type, post)
    action || post ? "#{format_action(action)}#{type.underscore}" : "#{type.underscore.pluralize}"
end
```

Routes:

```
    resources :blogs, controller: 'posts', type: 'Blog' do 
          resources :comments, except: [:index, :show]
    end
    resources :videos, controller: 'posts', type: 'Video'
    resources :posts
```

Post controller:

```
    before_action :set_post, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
    before_action :set_type
    def index
        @posts = type_class.all
    end
    ...
    private 

    def set_type
        @type = type
    end

    def type
        Post.types.include?(params[:type]) ? params[:type] : "Post"
    end

    def type_class
        type.constantize
    end

    def set_post
        @post = type_class.find(params[:id])
    end
```

Posts Helper:

```
    def sti_post_path(type = "post", post = nil, action = nil)
        send "#{format_sti(action, type, post)}_path", post 
    end

    def format_sti(action, type, post)
        action || post ? "#{format_action(action)}#{type.underscore}" : "#{type.underscore.pluralize}"
    end

    def format_action(action)
        action ? "#{action}_" : ""
    end
```

Post index.html

```
    <% @posts.each do |p| %>

    <h2><%= p.title %></h2>
    Created at: <%= p.created_at %><BR>
    Created by: <%= p.user.name %><P>
    <%= link_to 'Details', sti_post_path(p.type, p) %><P>
    <% end %>
```

The error appears when I try to access index.html, and I haven't tried other links yet. I've tried removing 'underscore', then '_path' becomes an undefined method. I've also tried other suggestions such as 'gsub', but it also shows it as an undefined method, which leads me to think that it's a syntax error...

**UPDATE:**
I had attr_accessor :type and that made 'type' nil. So I removed that and now it is working

Comment: It isn't a syntax error, your `type` is `nil` somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your PostsHelper.rb

```
def format_sti(action, type, post)
    action || post ? "#{format_action(action)}#{type.underscore}" : "#{type.underscore.pluralize}"
end
```

This method's else portion has **type**.underscore. **type** may be nil here. To verify it, try this:

```
def format_sti(action, type, post)
    action || post ? "#{format_action(action)}#{type.underscore}" : "#{"post".underscore.pluralize}"
end
```

Comment: Thank you! I had to substitute both 'type' with "post" to have it work. Why was that the case?

Comment: I have an inkling of an idea. When I go to my rails console and call up post.type, it returns nil even though the description says it is either "blog" or "video".

Answer (score 0):

Try the `try` command, which will not return the `NoMethodError exception` and will return nil instead,

```
def format_sti(action, type, post)
    action || post ? "#{format_action(action)}#{type.try(:underscore)}" : "#{type.try(:underscore).pluralize}"
end
```

Definition:
  **Using `try`, a NoMethodError exception will not be raised and nil will be returned instead, if the receiving object is a nil object or NilClass.**

[Here is the reference](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.1/Object/try)

Comment: I tried that and it returned a different error, this type identifying '_path' as an unknown method from this line: 
        send "#{format_sti(action, type, post)}_path", post